# Xamarin Android - Set toolbar background as an image, not working as expected

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-toolbar, android-appcompat

I want to set an image to be the background for my toolbar, with the image scaled to fit. For some reason the image just renders below the toolbar. and I am not sure why. Any help would be greatly appreciate. I have tried many of the ways people have suggested online and non of them yield the result I am looking for.

Also: Setting the background programmatically has the same result.

Here is my view code with the background set to the image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_nav_drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_nav_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/header_bg"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/main_nav_view"
        android:background="#D3D2D2"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/style_menu_bg_color"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/main_menu_header"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/style_menu_text_color"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/style_menu_text_color" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I have also tried it this way with an ImageView in the ToolBar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_nav_drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_nav_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
          <ImageView
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_gravity="center"
              android:src="@drawable/header_bg"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/main_nav_view"
        android:background="#D3D2D2"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/style_menu_bg_color"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/main_menu_header"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/style_menu_text_color"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/style_menu_text_color" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out and getting working for my scenario. I added a relative layout, with an image view above the toolbar (in code, not actual screen position), then made the toolbar's background transparent and scaled accordingly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_nav_drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewplaces"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/header_bg"
                android:maxHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/main_nav_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="#00FFFFFF"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/main_nav_view"
        android:background="#D3D2D2"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/style_menu_bg_color"
        app:menu="@menu/main_menu"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/main_menu_header"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/style_menu_text_color"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/style_menu_text_color" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image]